# Issue in merging/mixing of two audio using AVMutableCompositionTrack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

## it crashes when i try to play the merged audio

I am trying to merging two audio file . They merged successfully, but I am seeing with a problem that when i play that audio with AVAudioPlayer it crashes . also there is a problem with formats as the merge audio only store with .m4a format if i save that audio with .wav format the it crashes.

---

func merge(audio1: NSURL, audio2:  NSURL) {

let finalURL = getMergeFileURL()

```
    let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 100

    //This object will be edited to include both audio files
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()

    let compositionAudioTrack1:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    //let url1 = audio1
    let avAsset1 = AVURLAsset(url: audio1 as URL, options: nil)
    let tracks1 =  avAsset1.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let assetTrack1:AVAssetTrack = tracks1[0]
    let duration1: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30.0, preferredTimeScale)
    let startCMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Double(30.0), preferredTimeScale)
    let timeRange1 = CMTimeRangeMake(startCMTime, duration1)

    let compositionAudioTrack2:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    //let url2 = audio2
    let avAsset2 = AVURLAsset(url: audio2 as URL, options: nil)
    let tracks2 =  avAsset2.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let assetTrack2:AVAssetTrack = tracks2[0]
    let duration2: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30.0, preferredTimeScale)
    let startCMTime2 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Double(30.0), preferredTimeScale)
    let timeRange2 = CMTimeRangeMake(startCMTime, duration1)


    //Insert the tracks into the composition
    do {

        try compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(timeRange1, of: assetTrack1, at: kCMTimeZero)

        try compositionAudioTrack2.insertTimeRange(timeRange2, of: assetTrack2, at: duration1)


    } catch {

        print(error)

    }

    //Perform the merge
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport!.outputURL = finalURL as URL // final url is the url of that merged file 
    assetExport!.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport!.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
        default:
            print("complete")

        }

    })
```

}

Comment: Can you give any info on the crash?

Comment: i will give u all the details which u want . if i save the audio with .m4a format then it goes in the complete block but if i try to play that merged audio the nothing to play ? But if i save the audio with .wav format then it goes in the complete block but if i try to play that merged audio the app crashes ...

Comment: I'm asking about the specifics of the crash. What kind of crash is happening? Do you have logs from the crash?

Comment: Crash due to optional nil value

Comment: OK, that's helpful. Can you let us know what line it occurs on?